# Partitioning a metric space with interior, exterior and boundary of a set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Given a set $A$ in a metric space $(X,d)$, why do its interior $A^{\circ}$, its complement's interior ($X$$\setminus$$A)^{\circ}$ and its boundary $\partial$$A$ form a partition of the whole space? I saw this was presented as a given fact in a few posts but no one really proved it.

My try: First, I proved the three are disjoint. Then, I defined an open ball $B(x, \epsilon)$ around an arbitrary point $x$ $\in$ $X$. If there exists $\epsilon$ $\gt$ $0$ for which the ball is contained in $A^{\circ}$, then $x$ $\in$ $A^{\circ}$. Same for $x$ $\in$ ($X$$\setminus$$A)^{\circ}$ (if there exists $\epsilon$ $\gt$ $0$ such that the ball is contained in ($X$$\setminus$$A)^{\circ}$ then $x$ $\in$ ($X$$\setminus$$A)^{\circ}$). I just can't seem to find a way to prove that: if there isn't such an $\epsilon$, $x$ has to satisfy $x$ $\in$ $\partial$$A$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @user251257 Yeah but what about $X$ $=$ $\mathbb{R}$ and $A =$ $\mathbb{Q}$? The intersections will be empty and the boundary is $\mathbb{R}$. Doesn't that mess this proof a bit?

Comment: Yes exactly, so in that case the intersections you mentioned in the first comment would be empty, therefore your proof did not touch on this specific case. (What am I missing?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made an error in my comment. The correct argument is without the interior.

Let $x\in X$ such that $x\notin A^\circ$ and $x\notin (X\setminus A)^\circ$. Then, for every $\epsilon > 0$ we have
$$ B(x, \epsilon) \not\subseteq A $$
and 
$$ B(x, \epsilon) \not\subseteq X\setminus A. $$
That is, there exists some 
$$ y\in B(x,\epsilon) \cap (X\setminus A) $$ 
and 
$$ z\in B(x,\epsilon) \cap (X\setminus (X \setminus A)) = B(x,\epsilon) \cap A.$$ 
That ist, $x\in \partial A$.

*Note:* Obviously, $B(x, \epsilon)$ can be replaced by any neighborhood of $x$. Thus, the proof and the statement is valid in any topological space.

Comment: Nice! Got it. I think the moment I pass the 15 points mark, the up-vote will be public. At the moment, sadly, It is hidden. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's not just for metric spaces, but for arbitrary topologies.

Given any point $x\in X$, there are exactly three possibilites:

- Either there exists a neighbourhood of $x$ that contains only points from $A$. Then the point is in $A^\circ$.
- Or there exists a neighbourhood of $x$ that contains only points from $X\setminus A$. Then the point is in $(X\setminus A)^\circ$.
- Or there exists neither. Then the point is in $\partial A$.

It is obvious that at least one of the options always holds, and also that the last option cannot hold at the same time as one of the first two. So all that remains to show is that the first two cannot hold at the same time.

But that is also easy: Either $x\in A$ or $x\in X\setminus A$. Since every neighbourhood of $x$ contains $x$, each of those cases excludes exactly one of the first two options.